# Does calling close() on azure QueueClient stop the message pump gracefully?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

The template code when you create a worker role with a queue client provides a message pump implementation. The code has a comment in it saying:

```
// Initiates the message pump and callback is invoked for each message that is received, calling close on the client will stop the pump.
sourceClient.OnMessage(received =>
{
    //blah blah implementation
});
```

What actually happens when you call close() on the sourceClient? Do messages that are currently being processed continue? I.e. is this a graceful shutdown of the message pump? Or will calling close affect messages that are currently being processed by the message pump?

The documentation would lead me to believe it is, but there is this outstanding feedback item which would imply that there is no graceful shutdown mechanism for a message pump: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/4345733-provide-gracefull-shutdown-feature-to-message-pump

So what does souceClient.close() actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the full framework client (WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) `QueueClient` does not  stop message pump gracefully. Messages in flight that were not completed will have their delivery count increased.

> So what does souceClient.close() actually do?

That client is a closed source project. Best guess would be to raise an issue for it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).

Comment: So they will just reappear on the message queue after a timeout? They won't be lost?

Comment: Messages are never lost. They'd be retried, unless max delivery count is exceeded and then messages would be moved to the dead-letter queue.

Comment: OK thanks. So the real problem with graceful shutdown is messages being processed multiple times, or partially processed then processed again, rather than them being lost.